# Laravel5 ошибка вызова класса: Class Not Found

Tags: php, framework, классы, laravel, autoload

Создаю *api* для переводчика. Мне нужно принять *get*-переменную и создать экземпляр класса.

Когда я пытаюсь вызвать класс через строковую переменную, *Laravel 5* сообщает, что:

> class Not Found.

То есть, если сделать так:

```
$className = 'Spanish';
$obj = new $className;
```

Получаю

> Class Not Found.

Хотя, если сделать вот так:

```
$obj = new Spanish;
```

Все работает. На скобки не смотрите, пробовал с ними и без них.

В чем проблема и как ее решить? Может быть, есть какие-то альтернативные решения?

Пока сделал выбор класса через *switch*, но это не есть хорошо.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить неймспейс в $className. Или таки опечатка в названии

Comment: @alexeich Где опечатка? Класс подключен в use App\Spanish и при прямом обращение по имени все работает хорошо, но вот через переменную никак(

Comment: А можете кинуть файл, в котором это происходит?

Comment: @ValentineMurnik, вам уже ответили. В строке указывайте полный путь к файлу с классом. В вашем случае `App\Spanish`, видимо. Use в данном случае роли не играет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае нужно в строковой переменной использовать полное имя класса с пространством имен, т.е. `App/Spanish`.
Более подробно можете ознакомиться в документации: [Namespaces and dynamic language features](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php)

Comment: спасибо вы правы, помогло) Laravel 5, он такой)